# What's the difference between "if" and "whether"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, if-whether

Using *whether* is far more common.  It is certainly more formal.

> I would like to know whether it is a true story or fabricated.

But we can use *if* as well in the same sentence.

> I would like to know if it is a true story or fabricated.

So when do we use one or the other?

Comment: could it  be as simple as, 'if' to introduce a condition, and in all other circumstances, use 'whether'?

Comment: I consider this question: [Whether vs. If](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22379/whether-vs-if?rq=1) to be more pertinent. I think the top answer here answers quite nicely the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

**If** and **whether** are nowadays usually considered [subordinators](http://www.eslgold.com/grammar/subordinators.html).

Though their usages overlap, they are not totally interchangeable:

> Ask him whether/if I can come. ['if' more colloquial] ['or not' may be faintly implied]

......

> If/*Whether he is really a policeman, I'm a Chinaman.
>
> I will come if / * whether she is going to be there. [no 'or not' implied: no choice involved]

......

> They talked about whether / *if United still had a chance of winning
>   the league. ['or not' quite strongly implied: 'choice' of alternative possibilities]
>
> I will come whether or not / *if or not she is going to be there. [not may be placed at the end of the sentence] ['choice' (ie alternatives) overtly stated]

[See also](http://facstaff.gpc.edu/~cschroen/BONES/DEP/Noun/NC-SUBS/SUBS-NC-whether.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

**whether** is a choice between  alternatives, **if** is not.

The second sentence is not as clear as the first (maybe even syntactically incorrect) and should lose the "or fabricated"